# Sync a shared file without holding a mutex in rust

Tags: rust

I am using rust and I would like to build a high performance application where many threads are using the same file to do reading and writing. For safety, I need to wrap the File object in a Mutex.

I would like multiple threads to be able to write to the file at the same time. This means using a mutex for safety. The challenge is that after writing, I would like each thread to block on File.sync and not return until the file is synced. I don't however want to have to block other pending writes - the mutex should be released before File.sync is called.

Is there any way to do this? File.sync can take as long as 250 milliseconds for HDD storage, so it's completely unacceptable to only have one thread blocking on File.sync at a time. I need other threads to be able to call File.write while other threads are waiting for File.sync to return.

I tried using a Mutex to protect the File, but this resulted in extreme performance slowdowns because I could not call File.sync after releasing the mutex.

Comment: You do not need a mutex to read and write from a file at the same time. Sure the `Read` trait require `&mut self`, but there is an `impl Read for &File`, meaning only an immutable reference is required to read from it. Same for `Write`.

Comment: As noted by kmdreko, you can safely read and write to File without a mutex, and the same applies to `File::sync_data()` and `File::sync_all()`, both of which take `&self`. You can still use a dummy `Mutex<()>` to synchronize the writes voluntarily.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful to realize. So you can call sync_data on an immutable pointer to the file, and then if you need to use Seek() you can wrap the file itself in a mutex but still keep an immutable reference for syncing? I'll give it a shot